# regex match specific string to the character >

Tags: regex

I have two strings that look like this

```
X-Antivirus-Mail-From: firstemail@home.com via mail From: "Test UserAccount" <mygmail@gmail.com> there is more information past this

X-Antivirus-Mail-From: secondemail@home.com via mail From: <mysecondgmail@gmail.com> there is more information past this
```

I am trying to create a regex that will return this for the first string

```
From: "Test UserAccount" <mygmail@gmail.com>
```

and this for the second string

```
From: <mysecondgmail@gmail.com>
```

So far my regex patter looks like this

```
From: ["<].*
```

But I want it to end always on the character >.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
From: (".*?" )?<.*?>
```

Comment: how can I put this in java? the " character is giving me issues and if I \" them it doe snot work.

Comment: Java tends add anchors automatically it seems... so you will need to cater for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good starting point, but you need to match all characters until `>` so change it to:

```
From: ["<][^>]*>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work (tested with your two lines of text in [RegExBuddy](http://regexbuddy.com))

```
.*<(.*)>
```

The matches are returned in capture group 1.

[image: RegexBuddy screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
mail (From: .*\s*<.*>)
```

The content in the round bracket should be matched as a group, which should allow you to extract the text you need without any issues.

Edit, since you mention the use of Java:

You will need to do something like so:

```
^.*mail (From: .*\s*<.*>).*$
```

By default Java adds anchors to the String which might make it more difficult for you to match.

You can take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) Regex tutorial from Oracle.

This works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "X-Antivirus-Mail-From: firstemail@home.com via mail From: \"Test UserAccount\" <mygmail@gmail.com> there is more information past this";
        String str2 = "X-Antivirus-Mail-From: secondemail@home.com via mail From: <mysecondgmail@gmail.com> there is more information past this  ";


        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^.*mail (From: .*\\s*<.*>).*$");
        Matcher m1 = pat.matcher(str1);
        if (m1.matches())
        {
            System.out.println(m1.group(1));
        }

        Matcher m2 = pat.matcher(str2);
        if (m2.matches())
        {
            System.out.println(m2.group(1));
        }

    }
```

Yields:

```
From: "Test UserAccount" <mygmail@gmail.com> 
From: <mysecondgmail@gmail.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\sFrom: ("[^"]+"\s)?(<[^>]+>)
```

Working on: http://regexr.com?2vbu3

**Update:** in Java you'll need to escape the `"` with `\` like so:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\sFrom: (\"[^\"]+\"\s)?(<[^>]+>)");
```

Comment: how can I get this to compile in java using the " character?